GCP PubSub behavior with a dynamic number of subscribers
I have a Cloud Run FastAPI app that subscribes to a PubSub subscription. It's going to handle bursty traffic, so there may be zero instances or there may be 20 at a given time.
Let's say I have 10 containers running and a message gets published. Does the message
a.) get sent to all 10 container subscribers
b.) gets sent to one of the known subscribers, and assuming it gets ACK'd, doesn't get sent to others
c.) something else?
Based on my reading of the documentation I believe it's option B but can't find anything that explicitly confirms the behavior. If it isn't behaving as option B does, is there a way to get it to? I don't care about the ordering of the messages for this use-case, just that one message isn't going to be processed multiple times.

If you have a single subscription, then option B is the behavior.
In general, there are two paradigms for having multiple subscribers:
Load balancing: The goal is to parallelize the processing of the load by having multiple subscribers using the same subscription. In this scenario, every subscriber receives a subset of the messages. One can horizontally scale processing by creating more subscribers for the same subscription.
Fan out: The goal is to have multiple subscribers receive the entire feed of messages. This is accomplished by having multiple subscriptions.
This is covered in the overview of the Pub/Sub service.
